# how will I append data I am selecting from a dropdown list to the next input field in yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I want to select courses from the course field, then let it show in my courses field and submit the courses to the database. or if someone can help me so my courses can appear has a checkbox and once i tick a checkbox, it appears in the courses field

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?=$form->field($model, 'student_id') ?>
<?=
$form->field($model, 'faculty_id')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Faculties::find()->asArray()->all(), 'faculty_id', 'faculty_name'), [
    'prompt' => 'Select Faculty',
    'onchange' => '$.post("' . Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('/departments/lists?id=') . '"+$(this).val(), function(data) {
                            $("select#registrations-department_id").html (data);
                        });'
        ]
);
?>
<?=
$form->field($model, 'department_id')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Departments::find()->asArray()->all(), 'department_id', 'department_name'), [
    'id' => 'registrations-department_id',
    'prompt' => 'Select Department',
    'onchange' => '$.post("' . Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('/courses/lists?id=') . '"+$(this).val(), function(data) {
                            $("select#registrations-course_id").html (data);
                        });'
]);
?>

<?=
$form->field($model, 'course_id')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Courses::find()->asArray()->all(), 'course_id', 'course_name'), [
    'id' => 'registrations-course_id',
    'prompt' => 'Select Course',
    'onchange' => '$.post("(selected:)."+$(this).val(), function(data){
                            $("#registrations-courses").append(data)
                        });'
]);
?>
<!--        <?//= $form->field($model, 'courses')->checkBoxList([]) ?> -->


<?=$form->field($model, 'courses') ?>
<?=$form->field($model, 'comment') ?>
<?=$form->field($model, 'status') ?>
<?=$form->field($model, 'created_at') ?>
<?=$form->field($model, 'updated_at') ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?=Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

### EDIT

this is my controller how do I save the courses in the database in the same column?

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Registrations();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($model->validate()) {
            // form inputs are valid, do something here
            $model->student_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
            $model->faculty_id = 1 ;
            $model->department_id = null ;
            $model->course_id = 1;
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect('../site/profile');
        }
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, your question is unclear regarding what do you want do you want a dropdown to have a option selected as a course and on selection the name of the course is copied to the field name `courses` ? or you want to have check boxes for every course?,

Comment: I want to have checkboxes on every course, then when i select a check box it should appear in the courses field and How would i save the multiple items into the database

Comment: for saving courses in the database you need to have the schema prepared, but you haven't specified any of the models other than `Registration` which I guessed via your controller action you added, please specify the correct models where you want to save the courses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`checkBoxList()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#activeCheckboxList()-detail) to create the list of checkboxes based on the courses list.

Change your `course_id` field to the following

```
$form->field($model, 'course_id')->checkboxList(yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(Courses::find()->asArray()->all(), 'course_id', 'course_name'), [
    'inline' => true, 
    'unselect'=>null,
    'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value){
        $checked = $checked ? 'checked' : '';
        return "<input type='checkbox' class='my-courses' name='{$name}' value='{$value}' {$checked} data-label='{$label}'>&nbsp;<label>{$label}</label>";
    }]);
```

add an `id` attribute to your `courses` field like below

```
$form->field($model, 'courses', ['inputOptions' => ['id' => 'courses']]);
```

and then add this javascript code to the top of your page

```
$js = <<< JS
        $(".my-courses").on('click',function(e){
                let course_name=$(this).data('label');
                let course_field=$("#courses");
                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    $("#courses").val()==''?course_field.val(course_name):course_field.val(course_field.val()+', '+ course_name);
                }else{
                    let regex=new RegExp(',{0,1}\\\s{0,1}('+course_name+')','g');
                    course_field.val(course_field.val().replace(regex,''));
                }
            })
JS;
$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Now if you select the checkbox the name of the course would be copied to the input field and when you submit your form you can get the fields in your `$_POST` array under your specific model index like below.

```
[course_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )

[courses] => asdas, shugal, spoon
```

You can verify by adding a `print_r(Yii::$app->request->post())` in your controller action inside the check

```
if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
     print_r(Yii::$app->request->post());
```

You can iterate on the `course_id` to save all of the `course_id` that were selected as checkboxes.